# How do I isolate playerid from soundcloud URLs so I can use API?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I want to use the soundcloud javascript API to handle audio files.  So I tried to get hold of some sample URLS and I found these:

https://soundcloud.com/howard-fines/why-are-jews-on-the-left?utm_source=soundcloud&utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=facebook

and

https://soundcloud.com/hoover-institution/president-45

There may be other types as well.

I need to write a general routine to isolate a playerid from ALL varieties of URL in soundcloud.

What is the playerid in the above examples, and how many types of URL are there in sound cloud?
Thanks.

Comment: Its not completely a duplicate, because I am asking for the various manifestations of URLs as well.  I can feed them into the routine provided, but only if I know the various types.  Plus that routine has to be integrated into my website.

Comment: Ok. That is the correct way to use the API, though, and you did way "I want to use the soundcloud javascript API".